# Does anyone know what's going on with my Listview?

Tags: flutter

I needed to insert a TextField to search/filter records, but I don't know what's going on.

When I click on the "Cães" option of the BottomNavigationBar, on main.dart,

I only get a CircularProgressIndicator and the data does show up.

Have any of you experienced this problem?

Does anyone know why my Listview doesn't show up?

```
import 'dart:convert'; 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:ssk_final/addeditpage.dart';

//import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

List<dynamic> list = [];

class CaesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // CaesPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CaesPageState createState() => _CaesPageState();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Cadastro de Cães"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _CaesPageState extends State<CaesPage> {
  String searchString = "";
  Future<List<Caes>> caes;

  Future getData() async {
    var url = 'http://.../api2.php?opcao=read';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  /*

  Future _showMyDialog(id, nome) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Exclusão'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Confirma a exclusão de ' + nome + '?'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Confirma'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  var url = 'http://.../api.php?opt=delete';
                  http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
                    'id': id,
                  });
                });
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Cancelar'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

*/

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    caes = fetchCaes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(1, 87, 155, 1),
        focusColor: Colors.blue,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        hoverColor: Colors.green,
        splashColor: Colors.tealAccent,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AddEditPage(),
            ),
          );
          debugPrint('Clicked FloatingActionButton Button');
        },
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Divider(),
          //SizedBox(height: 10),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
            child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    searchString = value.toLowerCase();
                  });
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0))),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
                    ),
                    labelText: 'Pesquisa',
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search))),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<Caes>>(
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return snapshot.data[index].nome
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchString)
                            ? Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                    new InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print(index);

                                        Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => AddEditPage(
                                              caes: snapshot.data,
                                              index: index,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                      child: new Container(
                                        child: Column(
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              (snapshot.data[index].nome),
                                              maxLines: 1,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              ('${snapshot.data[index].microchip}'),
                                              maxLines: 1,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              ('${snapshot.data[index].pedigree}'),
                                              maxLines: 1,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              (snapshot
                                                  .data[index].data_nascimento),
                                              maxLines: 1,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              (snapshot.data[index].sexo),
                                              maxLines: 1,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              (snapshot.data[index].castrado),
                                              maxLines: 1,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ])
                            : Container();
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return snapshot.data[index].nome
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchString)
                            ? Divider()
                            : Container();
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                }
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
              // future: list,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Caes {
  final int id;
  final String nome;
  final int microchip;
  final int pedigree;
  final String data_nascimento;
  final String castrado;
  final String sexo;

  Caes({
    this.id,
    this.nome,
    this.microchip,
    this.pedigree,
    this.data_nascimento,
    this.castrado,
    this.sexo,
  });

  factory Caes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Caes(
      id: json['id'],
      nome: json['nome'],
      microchip: json['microchip'],
      pedigree: json['pedigree'],
      data_nascimento: json['data_nascimento'],
      castrado: json['castrado'],
      sexo: json['sexo'],
    );
  }
}

class Titulos {
  Titulos({this.data, this.titulo, this.exposicao});
  // non-nullable - assuming the score field is always present
  final String data;
  final String titulo;
  final String exposicao;

  factory Titulos.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final data = json['data'] as String;
    final titulo = json['titulo'] as String;
    final exposicao = json['exposicao'] as String;
    return Titulos(data: data, titulo: titulo, exposicao: exposicao);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'data': data,
      'titulo': titulo,
      'exposicao': exposicao,
    };
  }
}

Future<List<Caes>> fetchCaes() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://.../api.php?opt=read'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var caesJson = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;

    return caesJson.map((caes) => Caes.fromJson(caes)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load Caes');
  }
}
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByzvQ.png)

Comment: Add `future: caes` to the FutureBuilder. There's no future the FutureBuilder is waiting for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant really provide an answer in your list view cause it needs more files to run for me. However I can provide you a nice way to search in a list for items and update it with a text field. You can copy and run the code in the main of a test project to see how it is working.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final StreamController<List<String>> _exercisesStreamController =
      StreamController<List<String>>();
  late Stream<List<String>> _exercisesStream;
  final List<String> _exercises = [
    "Running",
    "Swimming",
    "Football",
    "Basketball",
    "Volleyball",
    "Karate",
    "Ski",
    "Snowboard",
    "Baseball",
    "Running1",
    "Swimming1",
    "Football1",
    "Basketball1",
    "Volleyball1",
    "Karate1",
    "Ski1",
    "Snowboard1",
    "Baseball1",
    "Running2",
    "Swimming2",
    "Football2",
    "Basketball2",
    "Volleyball2",
    "Karate2",
    "Ski2",
    "Snowboard2",
    "Baseball2",
    "Running3",
    "Swimming3",
    "Football3",
    "Basketball3",
    "Volleyball3",
    "Karate3",
    "Ski3",
    "Snowboard3",
    "Baseball3",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _exercisesStreamController.sink.add(_exercises);
    _exercisesStream = _exercisesStreamController.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              onChanged: (String value) async {
                List<String> temp = List.from(_exercises);
                temp.removeWhere((element) =>
                    !element.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()));
                _exercisesStreamController.sink.add(temp);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                hintText: "search",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _listViewWidget()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _listViewWidget() {
    return Expanded(
      child: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
        initialData: [],
        stream: _exercisesStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(15),
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      snapshot.data![index],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you need further instructions i am happy to help.

Comment: @NIltonChagas if it solves your problem, Please, accept Grigoris' answer.
Thank you in advance